# Sound set on Channel from app data folder not working in android 10 and above

Tags: java, android, notifications

I have been trying setting `NotificationChannel` sound from app data folder, but it is working in android 9 or below only. On android 10 and above, it is playing default notification sound of device. i am using following code to set sound on channel.

```
 NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)ctx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        Uri sound = Uri.parse(ctx.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS) + "/Download/MyApp/Ringtones/new_ride.mp3");
        File file = new File(sound.getPath());
        if(!file.exists()) {
            sound = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" + ctx.getPackageName() + "/raw/new_ride");
        }
        AudioAttributes attributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ALARM)
                .build();
        String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "com.MyApp.driverapp.newride";
        String channelName = "RideRequest";
        NotificationChannel chan = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        chan.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
        chan.enableVibration(true);
        chan.setImportance(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        chan.setSound(sound, attributes);
        chan.setShowBadge(true);
        chan.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
        manager.createNotificationChannel(chan);
    }
```

Here it returns `file.exist` to `true`, but still not playing notification sound from folder given.

Please advise, is there any changes in setting channel sound from android 10 onwards

Comment: You are nowhere using file.

Comment: What is the value of sound.toSteing()? Dus it have a scheme? If not make it a file scheme.

Answer (score 0):

For Android 10 or Higher, you want to convert your normal path to `ContentUri` below function helps you convert the path into `ContentUri`

```
@SuppressLint("Range")
    private Uri ContentUri(Context context, String path) {
        File file = new File(path);
        String filePath = file.getAbsolutePath();

        Uri mediaStore = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        String contentUri = "content://media/external/audio/media";

        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(mediaStore, new String[]{"_id"}, "_data=? ", new String[]{filePath}, null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            return Uri.withAppendedPath(Uri.parse(contentUri), "" + cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));
        } else if (!file.exists()) {
            return null;
        } else {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put("_data", filePath);
            return context.getContentResolver().insert(mediaStore, values);
        }
    }
```

- And Use Function Like this

  ```
     chan.setSound(ContentUri(ctx,sound.getPath()), attributes);
  ```